# Chracterizing quartic polynomials F such that $F, F',F''$ have only real rational roots.

Tags: calculus, field-theory

When designing friendly problems for a calculus class one comes up with such a question. (The cubic case is relatively easy.)

Of course one can generalize: Characterize degree $n$ polynomials such that the first $k$ derivatives, of order $0$ through $k-1$, have roots only in a certain field.

Comment: Won't it just give some ugly conditions on the coefficients, even in the cubic case? Or is there some natural way to look at this? I didn't give it some thought but I wondered if this is natural in some context, it feels like it could.

Comment: I changed tags ; it's not because we use field theory in number theory that the number theory tag is appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [paper](http://docserver.carma.newcastle.edu.au/836/1/macdougall_jim_galvinmacdougall.pdf), W. P. Galvin and J. A. MacDougall,`Nice' Quartic Polynomials - The Sequel.